# Excel Pivot table filter by cell value and cell value does not exist

Tags: excel, filter, pivot, vba

All

I am filtering multiple pivot tables by a cell value and this is working fine.

The only issue I have is when the cell value does not exist - the pivot tables show no data (which is fine) but the selected filter says 'All'.

Is it possible to change this to blank when the data does not exist? Or perhaps hide the pivot table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any .Visible property or similar that you could use to hide the pivot table, but you can certainly hide the columns that the pivot table occupies. pt.TableRange2.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the rows with VBA when the cell value is blank.

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=168361

I dont think it is possible to hide the entire pivot table.  Only the fields I believe.  Would be interested to see if it can be hidden though.